# Creating a pie-chart (of how many times a number is repeated) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I am trying to create a pie chart in Excel, but cannot figure out how to get it to work. I have a list (column) of numbers and the pie-chart needs to show how many times numbers are repeated (or how much of the “pie” each number takes up.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Select the frequencies, click **Insert, Pie** and right-click on the pie to **Add Data Labels**.

[image: SU516344 example]